# Differentiating between characters and Integers in Lisp

Tags: char, int, lisp

I have a list in Lisp which I am sorting through, and I want to make an if statement that checks if the current object in the list is a character or an integer.

Is there something like:

```
(if (EQUAL currentObject char)
...)
```

Or

```
(if (EQUAL currentObject integer)
...)
```

That I can use??

Many thanks.

Comment: Why not use a manual for such questions? Print this one: http://clqr.boundp.org  Or use this one online: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/Contents.htm

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to determine, which kind of object you have at hand.

```
(typep EXPR 'character) ;; ==> True, if EXPR evaluates to a character
(characterp EXPR)       ;; ==> ------------ " -----------------------
(typep EXPR 'integer)   ;; ==> True, if EXPR evaluates to an integer
(integerp EXPR)         ;; ==> ------------ " -----------------------
```

Have a look at the definition of [typep](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_typep.htm#typep), [typecase](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_tpcase.htm#typecase), [characterp](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_chp.htm#characterp), ...

```
(loop
   for element in list
   do (typecase element
        (integer #| element is an integer number ... |#)
        (character #| element is a character object ... |#)
        (t #| element is something not covered above |#)))
```

For many built-in types, there are predicate functions available, which can be used in to test, whether a particular value is an instance of that type. Often, these predicates are named after their base type's names, with a "p" appended ("stringp", "symbolp", "numberp", "consp", ...)